# On "canonical" extensions of functions from integers to reals

Tags: interpolation, continuity, analytic-continuation

Although this is essentially a port of [my MathSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4595745/extending-functions-from-integers-to-reals-what-properties-generally-matter), I think the users there tend to not understand how to interpret the questions from a [higher perspective](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/nPOV) (and often too literally). This is obviously fine for most questions I have, but this one in particular I would appreciate a high-level answer.

Essentially, my question(s) is / are?

> When extending functions from $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{R}$ to $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, such that $x\in\mathbb{Z}\implies g(x)=f(x)$, (or from some countable domain, to a continuum), why is there usually only one "canonical" extension?

For example, although there are uncountably infinite ways to extend a function like this, only one way has some intuitively nice property like it being holomorphic, log-convex, analytic everywhere, or etc. Such then becomes the "canonical" extension.

> Is there a some sort of meta-algorithm for determining what the "nicest" extension is, which fulfils the most 'desirable' properties, at least in some contexts?

For some explicit examples of what I mean, you're welcome to see the original MathSE post linked above, but given that the users here are more familiar with this kind of abstraction, I assume you are already aware of observations like these.

Comment: I do not see why you say that "there is usually one "canonical" extension. In each specific case, you need to use some additional properties to make it unique. For example, f(n)=n has a unique linear extension. To extend f(n)=(n-1)! you need log convexity for uniqueness. Each time you have to look for some additional property to achieve uniqueness.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko that's precisely what I mean actually. Somehow, linearity is the intuitive restriction for $f(n)=n$, log-convexity is the intuitive restriction for the gamma function, etc. There's clearly some reasoning behind why we choose these additional properties to come to uniqueness, just what is it exactly?

Comment: Log convexity is not an "intuitive restriction". That it makes the extension of Gamma unique is a non-trivial theorem (of Artin, I suppose), far from evident. So on my opinion, one has to think of such extensions on individual basis. There is no general principle here. Sometimes someone finds such a condition; for most sequences probably there is no "natural" condition.

Comment: If your function on the integers is given by some formula, then this formula usually gives an extension. But if not... what is the extension of the function f(n)=n-th prime?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko yes, I suppose I'm using the word intuitive rather loosely. It does make sense how we'd treat each function individually, but I was hoping there is some master theorem hiding out there in higher mathematics. As for a formula for the primes, I imagine one could manipulate the zeta function in some way to do the job, but I see your point anyway, how it does not make that much sense to speak of "primes-between-primes".